# Camera intent occassional fails

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, startactivityforresult

Am launching the camera intent from a dialog button and it succeeds 90% of the time.The other 10% of the time the intent launches and closes before taking a picture.Permissions are turned on,no error message is displayed and am using android 6.
What events may be causing this occasional fail?

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePicture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    alertDialog.cancel();
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What events may be causing this occasional fail?

Bugs in the particular camera app that you are using, primarily. I can't rule out the possibility that somehow your `alertDialog.cancel()` is at fault, as you might have a bit of a race condition there.

Comment: nice answer,thnks.is there a flag that can make this intent uncancellable?

Comment: @PeterMushirih: No. Please understand that there are ~2 billion Android devices, from thousands of device models. Those device models ship with *hundreds* of different camera apps, and users may elect to install other camera apps themselves. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` can be invoking any of those.